# How to use single object instance for class to set the multiple member value?

Tags: c#, .net, class, object, webforms

Curretly i am using below code to set the DateRanges Class member variables.

```
       DateRanges DateRanges1 = new DateRanges();
       DateRanges DateRanges2 = new DateRanges();
       DateRanges DateRanges3 = new DateRanges();

        DateRanges1.Label = "Last Week";
        DateRanges1.Range = Lastweek;
        this.dateRange.Ranges.Add(DateRanges1);
        DateRanges2.Label = "Last 1 Month";
        DateRanges2.Range = Lastmonth;
        this.dateRange.Ranges.Add(DateRanges2);
        DateRanges3.Label = "Last 2 Months";
        DateRanges3.Range = Last2month;
        this.dateRange.Ranges.Add(DateRanges3);
```

I want to reduce the code in this. is there any way to do this.

Here DateRanges, class that have label(string type), ranges(object) members.
this.daterange.ranges is my custom component property.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: How do you expect a single property in a single object to have multiple values? It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: Hi  Jon i want just to know is this possible to use single object (DateRanges1) to set my Last 1 month values  to my Rangesthis.dateRange.Ranges.Add(DateRanges1);. Again i want to reuse this DateRanges1 to set another value  like last one  month this.dateRange.Ranges.Add(DateRanges1). instead of going dateranges2, dateranges3

Comment: How would you expect that to be possible? If `dateRange.Ranges` has three references to the same object, how do you expect it to display three different values?

Comment: Ok Jon thanks for clarification, Then is there any other way to optimize this code

Comment: What makes you think this is actually a performance bottleneck to start with? (I can think of several ways I'd improve the readability, but that's a different matter...)

Comment: hi jon given answer in this forum helped me. Thanks

Comment: Do you understand that has no performance advantages over your current code?

Comment: yes i can but want to reduce the lines of code so only asked

Comment: You never *mentioned* reducing lines of code. There are much, much better ways of doing that. If you're actually interested in cleaner source code, please unaccept the current answer (which doesn't really help on that front) and edit your question to be much clearer. (Please tell us the type of `dateRange.Ranges` too.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Why it doesn't? OP asked how to reuse the variable(he called it object, but I understood what he meant), and I've answered that.

Comment: hi jon, i have edited my code. but what 3615 gives helped me to reduce the no of line so i have accepted that

Comment: @3615: Original code: 13 lines. Your code: 18 lines. How does that reduce the number of lines? Even after removing white-space-only lines, it doesn't. Basically the OP hasn't been clear about what they're trying to improve - and if it's readability, there's much more that can be done than your current answer.

Comment: @SasiDhivya: Going from 13 lines to 18 lines isn't really a reduction, is it?

Comment: @SasiDhivya: And you still haven't told us the type of `dateRange.Ranges`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Look at the question, it's about how to reuse the variable(wrongly called object), not about lines of code.

Comment: Ranges is object type custom component property Jon

Comment: @SasiDhivya: I very much doubt that its type is `object`, otherwise you couldn't call `Add` on it...

Comment: @3615: Please read the comments ("yes i can but want to reduce the lines of code so only asked") and the updated question ("I want to reduce the code in this").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this code cleaner, I'd suggest:

- Renaming `Lastmonth` etc to follow .NET naming conventions
- Not bothering with any separate variables (but if you do, make them follow .NET naming conventions too)
- Renaming `DateRanges` to `DateRange` (as it only appears to be a single date range)
- Creating a constructor for `DateRange` accepting the range and the label

You can then have:

```
dateRange.Ranges.Add(new DateRange(LastWeek, "Last Week"));
dateRange.Ranges.Add(new DateRange(LastMonth, "Last 1 Month"));
dateRange.Ranges.Add(new DateRange(Last2Months, "Last 2 Months"));
```

Or possibly (depending on the type of `Ranges`):

```
// Here AddRange would be expected to accept IEnumerable<DateRange>
dateRange.Ranges.AddRange(new[] {
    new DateRange(LastWeek, "Last Week"),
    new DateRange(LastMonth, "Last 1 Month"),
    new DateRange(Last2Months, "Last 2 Months")
});
```

Both of those are considerably cleaner IMO than using an object initializer and an unconventional local variable name.

If you're doing this around the same code you're initializing `dateRanges`, you could just use:

```
dateRanges = new FooBar // Whatever the type actually is
{
    // Other properties as well
    Ranges =
    {
        new DateRange(LastWeek, "Last Week"),
        new DateRange(LastMonth, "Last 1 Month"),
        new DateRange(Last2Months, "Last 2 Months")
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok jon i will check let you know soon

Comment: @SasiDhivya These are good recommendations, if you have the possibility you should follow these.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks the second options suites for me. Sorry for uncleared query jon

Answer (score 1):

You can have only one variable instead of 3 variables:

```
    var DateRanges = new DateRanges {
        Label = "Last Week",
        Range = Lastweek
    };
    this.dateRange.Ranges.Add(DateRanges);

    DateRanges = new DateRanges {
        Label = "Last 1 Month",
        Range = Lastmonth
    };
    this.dateRange.Ranges.Add(DateRanges);

    DateRanges = new DateRanges {
        Label = "Last 2 Months",
        Range = Last2month
    };
    this.dateRange.Ranges.Add(DateRanges);
```

Comment: @SasiDhivya You still have 3 instances though, obviously. Not sure what you are trying to gain.